# How do get to the bottom with a OpenCL kernel build error using Cloo with .NET?

Tags: c#, opencl, cloo

I am currently using VS2013. I have created a very simple C# solution that aims to use the Cloo with a simple class:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Cloo;

namespace ClooTest
{
    class Test
    {
        public static void main_entry(byte[] args)
        {
            ComputePlatform platform = ComputePlatform.Platforms[0];

            ComputeContext context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.Gpu,
            new ComputeContextPropertyList(platform), null, IntPtr.Zero);

            ComputeCommandQueue queue = new ComputeCommandQueue(context,
            context.Devices[0], ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);

            // get and build the source code
            ComputeProgram program = new ComputeProgram(context, new string[] { kernelCode });
            program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            // pick the fucntion
            ComputeKernel kernel = program.CreateKernel("add_data");

            // create a ten integer array and its length
            byte[] data1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            byte[] data2 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int size = data1.Length;

            /* allocate memory */
            ComputeBuffer<byte> data1buffer = new ComputeBuffer<byte>(context,
            ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite, data1);

            ComputeBuffer<byte> data2buffer = new ComputeBuffer<byte>(context,
            ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite, data2);

            kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, data1buffer); // set the byte array
            kernel.SetMemoryArgument(1, data2buffer); // set the byte array
            kernel.SetValueArgument(2, size); // set third argument as size;

            // execute
            queue.ExecuteTask(kernel, null);

            // wait for completion
            queue.Finish();

            // output results
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(data1[i].ToString());
        }
        #region Kernels
        private static string kernelCode = @"__kernel void add_data(__local char* data1, __local char* data2, __local int n)
                        {
                            data1[0]=data1[0]+data2[0];
                        }";

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And while I have no problems building the solution in Visual Studio I keep getting an "**OpenCL error code detected: BuildProgramFailure**." when trying to build the program using "**program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero)**". The kernel code looks fine but I have been at this for a couple of nights now and can't seem to figure out what is going on. As you can probably tell I am very new to Cloo, I have gotten a few ideas from examples online but I am probably doing something wrong at a very simple level. Any suggestions would be great.

I've downloaded all the latest OpenCL drivers for my graphics cards.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check the error return code from `program.Build` (if it returns one; I don't know your framework that is wrapping the OpenCL API).

To get more details about why the build failed, you need to call whatever your framework puts around `clGetProgramBuildInfo` with the `cl_program_build_info` parameter set to `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG`. That will tell you what the compile error is and what line it occurred on.

Just guessing as to the erros:

1. I don't think `__local int n` is right, it should just be `int n`.
2. I don't think `__local char* data1, __local char* data2` is correct either; these should probably be `__global char* data1, __global char* data2` (local memory is an advanced topic).

Comment: I've tried just stripping the kernel function down to just a simple int add_data(){ return 0; } and still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

To get specific kernel errors you should try catch program.Build and call GetBuildLog.
Something like this:

```
try{
   program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   String buildLog = program.GetBuildLog(context.Devices[0]);
   Console.WriteLine("\n********** Build Log **********\n" + buildLog + "\n*************************");
}
```